# Smooth transition when fadeIn relative divs with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make a navigation where you click on what you want (like about page) and the current page would fadeout and the about page would fadeIn.

The problem I'm having is that when The divs are positioned relative it will have a kind of "jumping" animation because the first div will slowly fadeOut and eventually get hidden completly now the new div jumps to the position where the old div was.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I mean. 
http://jsfiddle.net/285d2x9v/

Just click the boxes and you see the next box jump

```
$('.index').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $('.about').fadeIn();
    });
```

Is my basic approach, because I want an animation for hiding the div aswell. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete) complete callback in order to call your fadeIn when the out is completed.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.about').hide();

    $('.index').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
            $('.about').fadeIn();
        });

    });

    $('.about').click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
            $('.index').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/segr6z4o/

Comment: damn that's a sweet solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is the following...

```
     $('.index').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('.about').fadeIn();
        });
    });

    $('.about').click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function(){
            $('.index').fadeIn();
        });
    });
```

Explanation of code... `$(selector).[animation]([animation duration], [callback]);`

The callback is a function that will execute after the current animation is completed. You can modify the duration whatever you like. Do keep in mind that duration is in **Milliseconds**.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Jsfiddle to achieve your expected result, the main idea is to stack the elements using absolute positioning, then when you click the element we can avoid the jumping-in effect like you describe.

jsfiddle.net/285d2x9v/5/

Comment: well yeah but I want the elements to stay relative. The other solutions are better in my opinion